# What could cause intermittent 'Permissions Denied' errors in DatagramChannel connect() calls on Android?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, permissions, udp

I'm seeing intermittent error reports from my end users' devices like:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Net.java)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:466)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.connect(DatagramChannelImpl.java:759)
    at tech.httptoolkit.android.vpn.SessionManager.createNewUDPSession(SessionManager.java:159)
```

That last line is here: https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit-android/blob/2d514dce3079d23b7a500580b202ae4f7767eaaa/app/src/main/java/tech/httptoolkit/android/vpn/SessionManager.java#L152.

The application does already [request INTERNET permission](https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit-android/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L7), and connections do work in general, they just fail like this intermittently.

I don't have much more information on the exact request that's failing, and I can't easily reproduce the issue myself for testing, so I'm debugging blind.

What are the possible causes of this error?

Answer (score 1):

It is being refused permission to connect, by the local operating system.

- IPv6 support was added in Java 1.4
- There's been issues with IPv6 (on Java 7)

Try to disable IPv6 on both server and client machines. (For android you can select IPv4, inside your "Mobile network" under the voice "APN Protocol")

Comment: I haven't confirmed 100% that this is the cause, but it's a strong candidate and I don't have any better answers, so the bounty's yours!